# Drawing text using font from file not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to load a private font, using System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection. **The goal is not to have to install the font on the system.**

All the examples i find it look pretty simple. Just load using PrivateFontCollection and then create a font from it.

Below my simple class to test it.

It works only if i install the font. In not, the text is printed in the dialog preview as using some default font. I checked that the font is correctly loaded.
What i'm missing ? Thank for any help.

```
public partial class Test : Form
{
    private PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
    System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection privateFonts;
    private Font _barCodeFont;

    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        privateFonts = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
        privateFonts.AddFontFile("Code128.ttf");
    }

    private void btbTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
        pd.DocumentName = "Label";

        PrintPreviewDialog pp = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        pp.Document = pd;
        pp.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        pp.ShowDialog();

    }
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        _barCodeFont = new Font(privateFonts.Families[0], 12, FontStyle.Regular);
        ev.Graphics.DrawString("Should Be a bar code", _barCodeFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
    }      
}
```

Comment: I think this is by design.  Googling this finds a wasteland of people trying to solve this without much on answers.  Ultimately, I think the font needs to be installed on the machine in order to print it.  Otherwise a typical work around is to bitmap it into an image, but the quality will obviously suffer.

Comment: @LarsTech: this link provides a working example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Dan-o Not for the PrintPreviewDialog it doesn't, which is where this OP is having his problems.  I repro-ed it, and it works on a form, but not in the preview dialog.

Comment: Are you trying to print barcode fonts? You are opening up a big bag of hurt as these things create huge multi-MB spool files and print horribly as the driver tries to dither and anti-alias them. I strongly suggest using graphics primitives to draw barcodes; there are plenty of .NET libraries for doing this.

Comment: @MiguelSv: This link may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946986/unable-to-view-micr-font-in-print-preview

Comment: @ByteArtisan why not just install the font and then removing it when your done?

Comment: @JohanJvRensburg: Just because it should not be needed too. And adds an potential fail point,ex: may require more privileges, have to check is is already there.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    Font _barCodeFont = new Font(privateFonts.Families[0], 12, FontStyle.Regular);
    ev.Graphics.DrawString("Should Be a bar code", _barCodeFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    ev.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

and remove
 private Font _barCodeFont;